# About messages from UITapGestureRecognizer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

The following is from documentation :

> Although taps are discrete gestures, they are discrete for each state of the gesture     recognizer; thus the associated action message is sent when the gesture begins and is sent for each intermediate state until (and including) the ending state of the gesture.

The above passage seems to indicate that more than one message is sent.  The messages would include a "begin" message and an "end" message.  But somehow I just get the "gesture end" message.  Is there any way I can get both the tap begin and end message ?  (What I wish to track is - "begin" : the moment the user touches the screen and "end" : the moment the user lifts his finger away from the screen.)

Hope that somebody who is knowledgable on this could help ...

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITapGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UITapGestureRecognizer

Comment: I was also confused by the documentation, which goes on to say `Code that handles tap gestures should therefore test for the state of the gesture` and lists code to test for the `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded` state. All this seeming to indicate that the tap gesture recognizer would send more than just the ended event.

Comment: Yep, but that stands in stark contrast to the simple truth that we see only the one event and that the [Handling UIKit Gestures](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touches_presses_and_gestures/handling_uikit_gestures) even tells us that our handler will be called “exactly once” for discrete gestures. I suspect that there’s some edge case that can cause multiple events to be triggered (otherwise all those caveats they added to the `UITapGestureRecognizer` documentation don’t make sense), but it’s not clear how...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

      NSDate *date1 = [NSDate date]; //user touches the screen


}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

      NSDate *date2 = [NSDate date];  //user lifts his finger away from the screen

}
```

Comment: `The UIGestureRecognizerSubclass.h header file contains a class extension that declares methods intended to be called or overridden only by subclasses of UIGestureRecognizer. ` That method won't be send to delegate. They can be overridden only.

Answer (score 15):

The `UITapGestureRecognizer` only fires when the gesture state is `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded`

If you want to use a gesture recogniser to detect the start and end of a press, use the `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`, with the `minumumPressDuration` set to 0

Comment: Thanks! Guess this could be the best answer.  Just that I'd already implemented and tested the earlier suggestion.  And it seems to work also.  But your solution is more elegant. Thanks for your kind assistance ...

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use `- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` method ?

Comment: `The UIGestureRecognizerSubclass.h header file contains a class extension that declares methods intended to be called or overridden only by subclasses of UIGestureRecognizer. ` That method won't be send to delegate. They can be overridden only.