# state for UITapGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, ios5, uigesturerecognizer

The `UIGestureRecognizer` reference says: "discrete events such as a **tap** or a swipe can not report changes within the gesture"

How can I get notified when a finger is just touching the screen (and hasn't left it yet), and get then notified when it leaves the screen?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can detect touches by using

> ObjC answer:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

> Swift 3.0 answer:

```
func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)
func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)
```

Comment: ... which is declared in UIResponder instead of UIGestureRecognizer

Answer (score -1):

Well your answer lies in your question title i.e. UIGestureRecognizerState. You need to check for the state of the gestureRecognizer in the target method. like:

```
- (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
           if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)     {
                // handling code     
           } 
           else {
                //do anything else
           }

}
```

These are the possible enums:

```
UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible,
UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan,
UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged,
UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded,
UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled,
UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed, 
UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized = UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded
```

May be that'll help.

Comment: No, the action from UITapGestureRecognizer is only fired once when the state is UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7566812/about-messages-from-uitapgesturerecognizer?rq=1