# Detect when 3D Touch Peek and Pop View is Canceled

Tags: ios, swift, 3dtouch

I have a `UITableView` with 3D Touch [Peek and Pop](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/peek_and_pop) enabled. I would like to be able to detect whenever the user peeks the view and whenever the user stops peeking the view without popping. I know that [previewingGestureRecognizerForFailureRelationship](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontrollerpreviewing/1621467-previewinggesturerecognizerforfa) exists. And I've tried to use it like this:

```
func previewingContext(_ previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, viewControllerForLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIViewController? {
        
        // Here's where I add the gesture
        let gesture = previewingContext.previewingGestureRecognizerForFailureRelationship
        gesture.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "state", options: .new, context: nil)
            
        let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let detailVC = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SongPreviewViewController") as? SongPreviewViewController
            
        return detailVC
    }
```

and then I add

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    
        // can recognize peeking and canceling commit
        if let object = object {
            if keyPath == "state" {
                let newValue = (change![NSKeyValueChangeKey.newKey]! as AnyObject).integerValue
                let state = UIGestureRecognizerState(rawValue: newValue!)!
                switch state {
                case .possible:
                    print("switch - possible")
                case .began:
                    print("switch - began")
                case .changed:
                    print("switch - changed")
                case .ended:
                    print("switch - ended")
                case .cancelled:
                    print("switch - cancelled")
                case .failed:
                    print("switch - failed")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But every time the peek view begins, `.ended` is called. How can I do this properly? [Here's the reference I used for this code](https://github.com/ShingoFukuyama/3DTouchDetectStateOfPeekPopCancel/blob/master/PreviewState/ViewController.swift).

Answer (score 1):

The UITapGestureRecognizer only fires when the gesture state is UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded as discussed in the following link:

[About messages from UITapGestureRecognizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7566812/about-messages-from-uitapgesturerecognizer?rq=1)

All gesture recognizers begin a multi-touch sequence in the Possible state (**possible**).If you like to get at most two states: **(.Possible)** and **(.end)** you can try this code (Xcode version 9.2, swift 3.2, target 11.2) .

1. Change your addObserver code(Added more options) :

   ```
   gesture.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "state", options: [.prior, .old, .new], context: nil)
   ```
2. Get the old and new value in your observeValue method like below. It will call **(.possible)** and **(.end)** states:

   ```
   override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {     
   // can recognize peeking and canceling commit
   if let object = object {
       if keyPath == "state" {
           var newValue:Int?
           guard let change = change else { return }
           let old = change[.oldKey] == nil || change[.oldKey] as? NSNull != nil ? "nil" : "\(change[.oldKey]!)"
           let new = change[.newKey] == nil || change[.newKey] as? NSNull != nil ? "nil" : "\(change[.newKey]!)"
           if change[.notificationIsPriorKey] as? Bool == true {
               newValue = (old as AnyObject).integerValue
           }
           else {
                newValue = (new as AnyObject).integerValue
           }
           let state = UIGestureRecognizerState(rawValue: newValue!)!
           switch state {
           case .possible:
               print("switch - possible")
           case .began:
               print("switch - began")
           case .changed:
               print("switch - changed")
           case .ended:
               print("switch - ended")
           case .cancelled:
               print("switch - cancelled")
           case .failed:
               print("switch - failed")
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

There's another function, `previewingContext(_:commit:)` which is used to tell you it will commit. You could use that to set a property, and if that isn't set you can tell the 3D Touch action didn't 'pop'. [Documentation.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontrollerpreviewingdelegate/1621366-previewingcontext)